# MySQL-Python Installation Error: Possible Architecture Incompatibility?

Tags: python, linux, mysql-python

I am attempting to set up my Django virtualenv production environment on a Linux shared host server. Installing python packages using pip goes fine until I try to install Mysql-Python, which crashes. Does anyone know why this is failing? Looking through the error log, I think it's an architecture incompatibility between the package and my python installation because of these lines:

> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.a when searching for -lc
>
> /usr/bin/ld: warning: i386 architecture of input file `build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.4/_mysql.o' is > incompatible with i386:x86-64 output build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.4/_mysql.o: In function` _mysql_field_to_python':

I was told the server is 64-bit and is running Python 2.4, although I'm not sure how to double-check the former. Ive been googling this issue for several hours but I've only found references to install/import errors on macs. I'm thinking perhaps I need to compile a different version of MySQLdb instead of just doing `pip install -E myvirtualenv MySQL-python` but I'm unsure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't get the same architecture through pip or your package manager, you will probably need to either recompile Python (which you might consider anyway -- Python 2.4 is old), or MySQLdb.

Unfortunately, a lot of Python libraries are not cross-compatible between i386 and x86_64 -- I've actually had exactly the same issue with HGSubversion (the actual issue was with subvertpy, but I needed that for hgsubversion) and cx_Oracle. My solution was to downgrade Python to 2.6 for i386. Stunk.